# Kinvey Business logic Master Password

Tags: business-logic, kinvey

I am currently using Kinvey only for the business logic. Everything else I am using other services. It seemed that I must be logged in to use business logic so I made one account and made the user register to that account when opening the app. I am confused if that will be an okay approach since I believe I saw on another post that after so many downloads, it will raise a flag on Kinvey's side. Is that true? I also just saw these images in the users section and am not sure what this means.

[[image: 2]]
[[image: 1]]

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question about pricing, you can review our pricing plans at https://www.kinvey.com/pricing/.

Kinvey monitors customers in the free developer plan to check if their usage exceeds the limits. We do this by checking API calls per month, number of active users, data/file storage used etc for your kid - not by App Store downloads.

If that happens, Kinvey support or sales will reach out to you to help you transition to the next pricing tier or help you to reduce your consumption with optimization or other options.

Your queries about master secret, authentication are best answered in this Kinvey security guide: http://devcenter.kinvey.com/rest/guides/security

Regards,
Wani
Kinvey Support

Comment: I am only using Kinvey for the business logic alone. Where could i find how many api calls I could make to the business logic on the free plan? Also, would it be wrong to be making, for example, 1000 api calls a month, from 1 signed in user just to use the business logic?

Comment: Yes, that's fine and well within pricing limits. Refer https://www.kinvey.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/Kinvey-Pricing-072016.pdf for detailed pricing. In free plan, BL execution has a limit of 2 seconds, which might concern you. Also, it might be worthwhile considering alternative architecture as using multiple services can potentially slow your app down.